# XSLT conditional key test

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am attempting to set a boolean variable.  If at least one entry within a key matches a condition, the variable should be equal to true.  Otherwise, it should be false. Assume the starting XML is:

```
<Test>
  <TestEntry exNum="111" exValue="99"/>
  <TestEntry exNum="222" exValue="99"/>
  <TestEntry exNum="111" exValue="101"/>
  <TestEntry exNum="222" exValue="99"/>
  <TestEntry exNum="111" exValue="99"/>
</Test>
```

Then consider the following approach I attempted, considering if exValue is above or below 100:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="PARAM">111</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="THRESHOLD">100</xsl:param>

  <xsl:key name="exKey" match="/Test/TestEntry" use="@exNum"/>

  <xsl:template name="exampleVariable">
    <xsl:param name="exParam"/>
    <xsl:param name="exThreshold"/>

      <xsl:variable name="exVar" select="key('exKey', $exParam)/@exValue &gt; $exThreshold" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$exVar"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="exampleVariable">
        <xsl:with-param name="exParam" select="$PARAM" />
        <xsl:with-param name="exThreshold" select="$THRESHOLD" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If $exParam = "111", I expect $exVar = "true".  If $exParam != "111", I expect $exVar = "false".

However the test is never passed and the variable is always false.  Do you have any thoughts on what I did wrong?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: I am guessing it is a typo with your question, there is a slight issue with the XSLT you have shown, in that you have an `xsl:with-param` underneath the `xsl:template`, which is not allowed! As well as correcting that, could you also show example of how you are using `xsl:call-template` to call the template. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I updated XSLT above. First time posting here, so I wasn't sure the best way to get code (which is genericized to protect client) into the editor.  I retyped it and obviously mistyped that line.

Comment: Note: the code above will likely work in most processors.  My issue turns out to be the specific processor being used by my client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine when I try it like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="exKey" match="/Test/TestEntry" use="./@exNum"/>

  <xsl:template name="exampleVariable">
    <xsl:param name="exParam"/>

    <xsl:variable name="exVar">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="key('exKey', $exParam)[@exValue &gt; 100]">
          <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="'false'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$exVar"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="exampleVariable">
      <xsl:with-param name="exParam" select="111" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There must be a problem somewhere that you're not showing us. Please edit your question and provide a ***complete*** example that reproduces the problem.

Also note that you can hugely simplify the way you are defining `exVar`, and reduce it from 10 lines to 1 line:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="exKey" match="/Test/TestEntry" use="@exNum"/>

  <xsl:template name="exampleVariable">
    <xsl:param name="exParam"/>

    <xsl:variable name="exVar" select="key('exKey', $exParam)/@exValue &gt; 100" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$exVar"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="exampleVariable">
      <xsl:with-param name="exParam" select="111" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's an alternative approach that doesn't use keys. It may not be quite as efficient as the key approach, but it should get the job done in most cases:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="Entries" select="/Test/TestEntry" />    

  <xsl:template name="exampleVariable">
    <xsl:param name="exParam"/>

    <xsl:variable name="exVar" select="$Entries[@exNum = $exParam]/@exValue &gt; 100" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$exVar"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="exampleVariable">
      <xsl:with-param name="exParam" select="111" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the tip on simplifying the variable definition. I have updated the example to exactly what I am testing. Interestingly, it behaves perfectly when tested in my personal XML editor.  When I test the same code with the same starting XML in my client's landscape (SAP) it behaves differently. Specifically, it works when $exValue = 111, but always returns false when $exValue = 222 (even when the threshold is set to 10).  I guess this is no longer an XSLT issue.  Thanks anyway for your consideration and guidance!

Comment: @MattDion Hm, it certainly is odd that it works for certain values but not for others. I've posted an alternative approach above that doesn't use keys. I don't think there's a huge benefit to using keys here unless the input XML is huge.

Answer (score 0):

Or even simpler:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="exKey" match="TestEntry" use="@exNum"/>

<xsl:param name="exParam" select="111" />
<xsl:variable name="exVar" select="key('exKey', $exParam)/@exValue &gt; 100" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="$exVar" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```